# Trying to loop over an object using Moment JS

Tags: json, angular, momentjs, lodash

I have a section that pulls in data from an array and displays it and groups it by month. In order for it to show the date object I have to remove a layer from the JSON file.

It feels like I'm missing something something very small and just need to make a tiny change to loop over the data array. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the table that displays the data:

```
<table class="table" *ngFor="let month of transactions | keyvalue">
    <tr>
        <th>{{month.key}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="table" *ngFor="let customer of month.value">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {{customer}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is the component that groups the data:

```
export class AppComponent {

  public transactions = {};
  // Sample Data
  customers = [
    {
      data: [
        {
          customer: {
            name: "John"
          },
          // transaction_date: "2017-04-18"
          transaction_date: "2019-9-22T13:56:11.971643+00:00"
        },
        {
          customer: {
            name: "Dick"
          },
          transaction_date: "2019-10-22T13:56:11.971643+00:00"
        },
        {
          customer: {
            name: "Harry"
          },
          transaction_date: "2019-7-22T13:56:11.971643+00:00"
        },
        {
          customer: {
            name: "John"
          },
          transaction_date: "2019-9-22T13:56:11.971643+00:00"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const monthName = item =>
      moment(item.transaction_date, "YYYY-MM-DD").format("MMM");

    // Establish groupBy array
    this.transactions = _.chain(this.customers)
      .groupBy(monthName)
      .mapValues(items => _.map(items, "customer.name"))
      .value();

    const byMonth = _.chain(this.customers)
      .groupBy(monthName)
      .mapValues(items => _.map(items, "customer.name"))
      .value();
    console.log(byMonth);
    return byMonth;
    console.log(this.customers2);
  }
}
```

If I format the Json differently it works, but I need it to work with the `data []` array as well.

```
// Working Array
  customers2 = [
    {
      customer: {
        name: "John"
      },
      // transaction_date: "2017-04-18"
      transaction_date: "2019-9-22T13:56:11.971643+00:00"
    },
    {
      customer: {
        name: "Dick"
      },
      transaction_date: "2019-10-22T13:56:11.971643+00:00"
    },
    {
      customer: {
        name: "Harry"
      },
      transaction_date: "2019-7-22T13:56:11.971643+00:00"
    },
    {
      customer: {
        name: "John"
      },
      transaction_date: "2019-9-22T13:56:11.971643+00:00"
    }
  ];
```

Comment: What's the output of `transactions` after the loadsh functions? And what's displayed when the code isn't working as you intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 this.transactions = _.chain(this.customers[0].data)

 const byMonth = _.chain(this.customers[0].data)
```

Working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k7shfc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

**UPDATE**

Your `customers` member variable is an array with only one element.

That was the reason for adding `[0]` to access it.

You simply access the first element in an array like that. Array name and an index value (zero based).

Few more examples:

`customers = []; // <-- simple array`

`customers = [{}]; // <-- simple array with one object in it`

How to access it?

`customers[0] // <-- first element`

Your case:

`customers = [{ data: [] }]; // <-- simple array with one object in it with a property "data" which is another array.`

How to access it?

`customers[0].data // <-- the solution`

Comment: That did the trick! Would you be able to explain what you changed? Does the `[0].data` piece force the array to loop over `data`?